# Stop a user from being able to see tables under a certain schema while connecting to the database through mail merge in MS Word

Tags: sql-server, database, schema, ssms

I am connecting to a database using mail merge in MS Word to access a group of tables. Half the tables are under schema_1 and half are under schema_2.

Currently, once I have connected to the database I can see all the tables listed, when I only want to be able to see the tables under schema_1. Nothing from schema_2.

I'm using sql server management studio 2005, and have a user set up whose details I must input to gain access to the database from MS Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many dbas feel that schema based security is the optimal approach to managing SQL Server security. You can assign permissions through statements such as:

```
Grant read On  Schema::[schemaz] To [userx]

 revoke read on Schema::[schemab] To [userx]
```

You may find this article interesting:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/schema-based-access-control-for-sql-server-databases/

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I inputted the code but I'm told there was an error with the word 'read'. That word doesn't seem to be listed as a parameter with the revoke command.

Comment: Sorry. It should be revoke select

Comment: Your welcome. Please try to create groups (roles) as much as possible. If you put users in roles and assign the permission to roles (even if some roles have only one member) your life as a DBA will be much, much easier. The ideal is users are in Windows groups which are members of roles. This way if a user transfers you don't have to open up SQL Server just move the user from one Windows group to another.